# SwiftUI / SwiftData / Custom Picker selection state doesn't change on new selection

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

I have a custom Picker with help from here, as my images get rendered way to big if I am using the normal Picker.

Problem is, I don't get it to work programmatically. it used to work until I inserted
the data from my model.

I have tried it with unwrapping, with tag and with id, but nothing will work.

And I know, the image won't change for now, but I'll try to figure that out, if I get the Picker to change value somehow.

Code below, with the belonging part:

```
@Query private var bonsai: [BonsaiModel]
@State private var selectedBonsai: BonsaiModel?

Section("Select Bonsai:") {
                    LabeledContent("Bonsai") {
                        HStack {
                            Image("d2")
                                .renderingMode(Image.TemplateRenderingMode.original)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(maxWidth: 60, maxHeight: 35)
                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3))
                            Menu {
                                // put the picker inside a menu, so users see the images in the menu
                                Picker(selection: $selectedBonsai) {
                                    ForEach(bonsai) { item in
                                        Label {
                                            if let spec = item.species {
                                                Text(spec.name)
                                                    .foregroundColor(Color("plainTextColor"))
                                                    .font(.footnote)
                                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                                    
                                            } else {
                                                Text("No species selected.")
                                                    .foregroundColor(Color("plainTextColor"))
                                                    .font(.footnote)
                                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                                    
                                            }
                                        } icon: {
                                            if let imageData = item.bonsaiImageData, // unwrapp data from item.image and store in imageData
                                               let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) { // Put imgageData in UIImage and store image in uiImage
                                                Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                                            } else {
                                                Image(systemName: "tree")
                                            }
                                        }.id(item)
                                    }
                                    
                                    
                                } label: { }
                            } label: {
                                HStack {
                                    if let species = selectedBonsai {
                                        Text(species.name)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color("plainTextColor"))
                                            .font(.footnote)
                                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    } else {
                                        Text("No species selected.")
                                            .foregroundColor(Color("plainTextColor"))
                                            .font(.footnote)
                                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    }
                                    Image(systemName: "chevron.up.chevron.down")
                                }
                                .tint(.secondary)
                                .imageScale(.small)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The Picker looks like this:

[image]

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag (not id) must match the data type of the selection, `selectedBonsai: BonsaiModel?`

So try using `.tag(item as BonsaiModel?)` instead of `.id(item)`

Comment: I had this before, but I did not worked out. But I figured it out. I have stumpled over my @Relationships. Instead of "spec = item.species" i should have used "item.species?.name" as the BonsaiModel get this from the SpeciesModel. Now it works as intended. Thanks for your quick answer, was kind of a push to re-look everything. :)